# How to get all NuGet related actions/rights?

Tags: nuget, authorization

As mentioned in some other posts, I'm having NuGet related problems, but my colleagues are not experiencing those problems. NuGet is a combination of local tools (C:\Program Files\NuGet\NuGet.exe) and a NuGet related username.

In order to determine where I'm having the issues, I'd like to verify if my NuGet rights (determined by the mentioned username) are the same as the ones of my colleagues.

Therefore I'd like to know if such a question can be asked:

```
Give me the complete list of things I can do with my NuGet username.
```

In case that exists, both me and my colleagues can launch it, and I can compare. In case of differences, I'll need to check my NuGet user rights. In case equal, my problems should be due to my local system.

Does anybody know if such a question/command exists and how it works?

Thanks in advance